# How to check if the user was redirected?

Tags: session, private, template-redirect

I need an advice on how to the following: 
I have registered *course* custom post type and created one for example *Course1*. *Course1* has child posts - some are private (e.g *Lectures*) and some are not.

When user tries to open *Lectures* user's meta field is checked and based on the value the content is displayed or the user is redirected to the parent. I have used `template_redirect` hook (might not be the right one). What I need now is to show some banner with notification (for example you cant see private content) on parent course post after redirection. How can I know that user has tried to open Lectures and it was redirected? I tried using session in redirect function but didnt make it (the banner was active on all *Course1* post). Could you please give me some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_get_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer) function to acheive your requirement.

Below is the useful code snippet for you.

```
    function wdm_referer()
    {
        global $post;

        if( post type is child  ) {

            $child_post_id = $post->ID;

            $parent_id = get_parent_course_id($child_post_id); // your custom function to get parent course id

            if( parent task is not completed ) { // a condition that you are checking on child page and redirecting

                // to get http referer
                $page_referer = wp_get_referer();

                // to get parent post permalink
                $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );

                // if parent course link is same as http referer
                if( $page_referer == $parent_permalink ) {
                    //user came from parent course. Your code to display in content
                }
            }
        }
    }

add_action('the_content', 'wdm_referer');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check this out once I come back from work. :) Where `parent task is not completed` I should check whether user can see child content, right?